# How to set cardView Gravity in RecyclerView Programatically

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gravity, cardview

I'm trying here to set the layout gravity of certain elements in recycler view to RIGHT so i did this in the recycler view adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessagesViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Message message = messagesList.get(position);
    if (message.getSenderId().equals(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()))
    {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        holder.messageCv.setLayoutParams(params);
        holder.messageCv.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        holder.senderTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        holder.messageCntnt.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
    holder.senderTv.setText(message.getSender());
    holder.messageCntnt.setText(message.getMessage());

}
```

But it didn't works

the recycler view looks like this [image]

Comment: I think that you want to set the gravity for `holder` and not `messageCv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you use `RelateiveLayout.LayoutParams`?
By the documentation:

`CardView extends FrameLayout`
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView

So you should use `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`

It has `gravity` field.
I believe you can use this one.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams#gravity

But it's not a best approach to set it programatically, better just to add the attribute to layout xml.

Comment: BUt the problem has not been fixed

Comment: Can you share the result? I  mean how it looks

Comment: It's just the same but with little left margin my code is like this ; FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.RIGHT);
            holder.messageCv.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: do you have something inside the CardView?

Comment: yes linear layout

Comment: it's hard to understand how it looks, can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244886/discussion-between-aymen-mellah-and-anatolii-chub).